# Handle possible null values in python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I use the following code to count the number occurrence of two values (1, -1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty(0, dtype=np.int)
tmp = [-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1, 1, -1]
a = np.append(a, tmp)

unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
r = dict(zip(unique, counts))
print r
if r.values()[0] > r.values()[1]:
    print r.keys()[0]
else:
    print r.keys()[1]
```

The problem is that `tmp` can be sometimes all 1s or -1s which causes to fail the printing. The possible solve I can think of is to add a null-like key of zero value. For instance, when `tmp=[1,1,1,1]`, `r` should be `{1: 4, -1: 0}` and visa versa. How can I modify this code to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick given that the input list/array contains only `-1` and `1` would be to use offsetted array (offset by 1 to make -1s as 0s and 1s as 2s) for binned counting with `np.bincount` and then slicing with a step-size of `2` to consider counting for `-1` and `1`  -

```
dict(zip([-1,1],np.bincount(a+1,minlength=3)[::2]))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [954]: a = np.array([-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1])

In [955]: dict(zip([-1,1],np.bincount(a+1,minlength=3)[::2]))
Out[955]: {-1: 3, 1: 6}

In [956]: a = np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1])

In [957]: dict(zip([-1,1],np.bincount(a+1,minlength=3)[::2]))
Out[957]: {-1: 4, 1: 0}

In [958]: a = np.array([1,1,1,1])

In [959]: dict(zip([-1,1],np.bincount(a+1,minlength=3)[::2]))
Out[959]: {-1: 0, 1: 4}
```

If you just need which one of `-1` or `1` has the bigger count, simply do -

```
np.bincount(a+1,minlength=3).argmax()-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for free, say you have

```
>>> uvalues = [-1,1]
```

which stands for the list of values to count.

What about doing `{uvalue:r.get(uvalue,0) for uvalue in uvalues}`

---

Use case

```
>>> a = np.array([-1,-1, -1, -1])
>>> unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
>>> r = dict(zip(unique, counts))
>>> r
{-1: 4}
>>> {uvalue:r.get(uvalue,0) for uvalue in uvalues}
{1: 0, -1: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other natural (and fast) solution using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) :

```
from collections import Counter

tmp = [1,1,1,1,1,1]    
c=Counter({1:0,-1:0}) # init
c.update(tmp)
#Counter({-1: 0, 1: 6})
```